# Fragment Hosting

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is a question for some knowledge.  I have a page adapter hosting 5 fragments.  4 of them are normal, but one of them is hosting a recycler view and a map view.  I want the map to respond to the recycler view onClick events.  I've done something similar with an activity hosting two fragments, but I'm not sure if it's possible with the setup I have.  If it is possible can someone point me to some reference/literature?  It might be I'm just doing too much.

Thanks.

Comment: You could provide your code in a [mcve] and maybe someone will help solve the problem. Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow. Besides, communication between 2 out of 5 fragments is not different than only two fragments as long as there is one activity holding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using interface you can get the data from the fragment 1 or 2 and then call the public method in fragment 5 to update the recycler view.  And you can store the reference of the fragments in sparsedArray